# Image flicker on background image

Tags: html, image, css, cross-browser

I use a background image on a div with percentage.
When my div is going very small the image is partial.
Portions are missing or the color is lighter.

[image]

image original
[image: enter link description here]

image on small width
[image: enter link description here]

How could I solve this problem ?
image format maybe?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cbn67ya5/

Comment: Can you reproduce with [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sf.net/e)?

Comment: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#dfcc05747c7ec002959df00755403bf7. When resize the result pane smaller

Comment: I guess it's a problem with the percentage width since a browser can't display anything on "half" pixels (eg. 12.5px) but he may have to while using percentage widths which leads to him not displaying anything or flickery images.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 1):

Using an SVG image the flicker is gone.
However, the interval betwen images is not always the same. 
It seems a small adjustement is done (i think it can't display anything on "half" pixels).

reproducible on this
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbn67ya5/6/)

Try to resize the span very slowly.

```
    #container .rule{
          background-image :  url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none' width='40' height='80'><rect x='0' y='1' width='1' height='100'/><rect x='10' y='1' width='1' height='30'/><rect x='20' y='1' width='1' height='50'/>    <rect x='30' y='1' width='1' height='30'/></svg>");
          background-size: 100% 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you're using a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) so lets analyze this before going into the background.

By using [`TD's`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) with a [`Table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) your lists are horizontal.

```
<table id="container">
  <td>hello</td>
  <td>hello</td>
  <td>hello</td>
  <td>hello</td>
</table>
```

So the above section of code makes...
[image]
You're applying your background on all off those [TD's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) (with the class `.rule`)

Meaning because you're using a percentage based width (it's going to fill the [`TD's`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) width) and reduce size+quality here.

A [SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) would help with quality but I don't see it solving your problem here.

If you want to [replicate a ruler](http://j4n.co/blog/css-ruler) you could use the [jQuery.Ruler](http://ruler.hilliuse.com/) plugin, my [JQuery Ruler](https://github.com/mikethedj4/jquery-ruler), or [this Pen](http://codepen.io/jelmerdemaat/pen/sBqfF) which does it using CSS gradients.

In the case below ([weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#47a350d5a3e725ed08960fc5c4aa691d)) I took my [JQuery Ruler](https://github.com/mikethedj4/jquery-ruler) and just used it as an image without the numbering marks. In a repeated background. (Notice I'm not applying it to TD's because for this case you'd want it on the parent.

```css
.ruler {
  height: 27px;
  background: #eee;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAaCAYAAAD1wA/qAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4AUREBciNhBoqgAAAIZJREFUWMPt2DEKAyAQBMA9n6An+P/3+QL17lLFIkUigRCQXdhumwEtVHrvuCFJVeMKCC4JIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEELIXyFjDMw5d9dau2YGM4OqhrvD3RERu695vjhF5G1VNVJK+NTT3d1Hq7V29I6vtR7tSilHu5zz1ztedkJ+FAFwxb/WA0m1Oj6D5YBIAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ruler"></div>
```

Comment: i want make ruler from scratch, for my project.
Svg seem to have an interesting behavior with little width. 
But the image does not seem to grow more than its original size.
However, it seems to work. any flicker

https://jsfiddle.net/cbn67ya5/2/

Comment: In your example there is no percentage. your image is repeted. I need too keep the same number of gradation whatever the width.